# 2 stack frames were collapsed. Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code has compiled successfully without any errors, but on my browser I'm getting this instead of output `Target container is not a DOM element`. Why is that? What am I missing?

I've tried `React.createElement` but it did not work.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.setState = {
      name: '', 
      greeting: `Good ${this.props.time},`
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
  onChange(e){
    this.setState ({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Container">
        <section className="section" >
          <label className="label">Name: </label>
          <input className="input" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={this.onChange} ></input>
        </section>
        <section>
          <p>{this.state.greeting} {this.state.name}</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Greeting;
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(<Greeting time="morning" />, document.getElementById('app')));
```

I expect it to show some output, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `<Greeting />` component directly to the render function:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Greeting time="morning" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Also, make sure that you add an element to your index.html with id `app`.

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Here is what i am getting on my browser
"""Target container is not a DOM element.
▼ 2 stack frames were expanded.
invariant
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:57
render
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22230
▲ 2 stack frames were expanded.
Module../src/App.js
src/App.js:32
  29 |   }
  30 | }
  31 | export default Greeting;
> 32 | ReactDOM.render(<Greeting time="morning" />, document.getElementById('app'));
  33 |"""

Comment: Have you added an element in your HTML? `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: I have added some elements in <dive id="app"></div> and it's working. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the root component remove **export default Greeting;**